# How to interpret WEKA results for binary classification dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, weka

I'm working on a binary classification dataset as below:

[Data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JroYa.png)

I ran it in WEKA through the J48 classifier and got the results:

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TBdz.png)

I need help understanding the meaning of these results.

I believe correctly and incorrectly classified instances are the results of the model on the testing data?

My main issues is understanding relative absolute error and root relative squared error.

Answer (score 0):

What the statistics are from depends on the selected evaluation strategy (training set, train/set set, train/test split, cross-validation).

If you are not familiar with Weka, I recommend you to work through the Weka MOOCs (free and available on FutureLean):

https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/courses.html